# Simple Questionnaire Array Program

Tags: java, random

I want to create a simple questionnaire program - there will be five questions and 4 answers each. Everything time it is run the questions and answers order will be random.

Ex:

1st run:

1. What is fruit colored red?
   a. Apple b.Pineapple
   c. Orange d. Pear
2. What shape has 3 sides?
   a. Square b. Circle
   c. Triangle d. octagon

2nd run:

1. What shape has 3 sides?
   a. Octagon b. Square
   c. Circle d. Triangle
2. What is fruit colored red?
   a. Orange b. Apple
   c. Pear d. Pineapple

--EDIT-- Here is the draft code I have made based on the suggestions:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    Random rand = new Random();

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arrList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    ArrayList<String> question = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> choiceShuffle = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> choice1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> choice2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> choice3 = new ArrayList<String>();

    int numQuestion = 3;
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt(numQuestion);
    int score = 0;
    String questionShuffle;
    questionShuffle = question.get(randomNum);
    choiceShuffle = arrList.get(randomNum);

    question.add("What is after a?");
    question.add("What is after b?");
    question.add("What is after c?");

    choice1.add("a"); choice1.add("b"); choice1.add("c");
    choice2.add("d"); choice2.add("c"); choice2.add("e");
    choice3.add("d"); choice3.add("a"); choice3.add("b");

    arrList.add(choice1);
    arrList.add(choice2);
    arrList.add(choice3);

    for (int x = 1; x <= question.size(); x++){
        System.out.print(question.get(randomNum));
        Collections.shuffle(choiceShuffle);
        System.out.println(choiceShuffle);
    }
}
```

}

Where am I going wrong here? and also I would like to create a variable named "score" that whenever the right answer is chosen, it will initiate score++. Open for suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? `String [] questions = new String[]{"Q1","Q2"};`

Comment: Look into Arrays and the Random object for a good starting point. If you have trouble using these, please post another question with the specific problem. A way to start this would be to create two arrays, one for questions, the other for answers with the questions and answers in the same indexes for both arrays and use the Random object to get an integer between 0 and the size of your array and then show the question with answers

Answer (score 3):

you can use the `Random` class available in Java for random number generation.

> ```
> Random rand = new Random();
> int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
> ```

here max will be your number of questions and in your particular case you can set min to 0, you can use `Swing` classes to design your GUI. Most IDEs like NetBeans/Eclipse have provisions to create `GUI` without writing explicit code. Now depending on your random number you can access the `question[rand]`. You can implement your questions and answers as `arraylists` and access your questions as question[rand]. You can shuffle your corresponding answers list using

> Collections.shuffle(answerList);

Edit: Here's a sample code for your reference:

> import java.util.ArrayList; import java.util.Iterator;  import
>   java.util.Random; import java.util.Collections;
>
> public class JavaApplication1 {
>
> ```
> public static void main(String[] args) {
>      /**  * Create ArrayList in ArrayList Object  */
> ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> quesAns = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
> ArrayList<String> answer = new ArrayList<String>();
> ArrayList<String> question = new ArrayList<String>();
> question.add("what's your fruit?");
> question.add("what's your shape?");
> answer.add("apple");
> answer.add("banana");
> answer.add("mango");
> quesAns.add(answer);
> ArrayList<String> answer2 = new ArrayList<String>();
> answer2.add("circle");
> answer2.add("rectangle");
> quesAns.add(answer2);
> Random rand = new Random();
> numQues = 2
> int randomNum = rand.nextInt(numQues);
> System.out.println (question.get(randomNum));
> ArrayList<String> answerListShuffle = new ArrayList<String>();
> answerListShuffle = quesAns.get(randomNum);
> Collections.shuffle(answerListShuffle);
> System.out.println(answerListShuffle);
>
> }
> ```
>
> }

This is just an example implementation. You can make up these arrayllists and add elements as you go inside your loops depending on the number of elements

Comment: I see, I started by creating two arrays: One for question which is String[] question, then 2nd array is for answers which is two dimensional array. String[][] answer. The problem is that im not sure how I will coordinate or tie up the specific answers to question while making them randomly show everytime the program is run. Appreciate your kind reply.

Comment: Better still you can use an arraylist of arraylist, this way all your questions and corresponding answers can be kept organized and bound to one another. The plus point of using an arraylist over an array would mean that you can dynamically allocate the size and it's not bound to a given size.

Comment: Using an arraylist of arraylist will hape you chain your answers to your questions. I'll give you an example: private static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> ques_ans = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(); This is your ques_ans structure, now you can add questions to this list, which will constitute the outer list and answers corresponding to them will constitute the inner lists, one list corresponding to each question. You can refer to the example in the link http://examplesofjava.com/arraylist/array-list-in-array-list-example.html

Comment: Just to confirm if I understand this, I will have a general Arraylist of Arraylist named ques_ans (at this example). My question is based on the link you provided, what you put in innerList is choices ex: innerList.add("Apple"); innerList.add("Pineapple"); etc. How are you going to put the questions inside and chaining four choices each?

Comment: maintain inner lists for all answers and in your loop you can add this inner list to the questions corresponding to your outer list. For eg, innerlist.add("apple") innerlist.add("banana"), (your options for say the first question). Now add these options to your outerlist as, outerlist.add(innerlist). Similarly for other questions, maintain separate inner lists. innerlist2.add("square", "circle", "reactangle") and add this to your outer list. You can maintain your seperate arraylist for your questions, choose a rand no between 0(inclusive) and your number of questions(exclusive).

Comment: Now display this question by random selection, access its options by accessing the inner arraylist corresponding to that question. using the same random number as generated before, shuffle this innerlist as i have shown in the answer and you're ready to go!

Comment: check out the edit i made to the answer and see if that helps you

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my post and included initial draft, any suggestions here?

Comment: You have to add the elements to your array first before you access them. In your edit attempt, you are trying to access elements of your quesans arraylist before you even add anything to it giving rise to a runtime exception

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use HashMap. because with HashMap you can map your answer object & question object together. I think it's easy for you.